# Qt threading does not seem to share equally over cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

I have a multithreaded application. However I noticed, I'm using OpenGL and this should not work well without semaphores. And it did. I added semaphores later, because they *should* be used.

Not so great is the fact that I now have a multithreaded application which does not really seem to utilise multiple threads or cores on the cpu.

My load balance always seems to be towards a single cores (of 4) with a difference of atleast 40%.

Do I need to switch a trigger in Qt's project file, or am I overlooking something else? It could be that this behaviour is expected, but clarification would be nice if so.

My platform is Ubuntu 11.10.

```
class DrawChunkThread : public QThread
{
    public:
        DrawChunkThread(World *world, int x, int z);
        void run();
        World *world;
        int x;
        int z;
        static QSemaphore *sem;
    private:
};


QSemaphore *DrawChunkThread::sem = new QSemaphore(1);

DrawChunkThread::DrawChunkThread(World *world, int x, int z) {
    this->world = world;
    this->x = x;
    this->z = z;
}

void DrawChunkThread::run()
{
    world->drawChunk(x, z);
    if (world->isInside) {
        world->drawInsideChunk(x, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are lots of factors to consider... Will be a good start to identify which thread consume how much cpu... try profiling

Comment: You don't say which platform you're using.  Regardless, you'll probably find your code is being serialised because perhaps all of your threads are hitting a single resource.  Worse than this, there are a host of problems you can get if you aren't cache friendly or f you're over-using critical sections and so on, that can result in poor threading performance.

Comment: Which language are you using? Is it C++? Please add the language tag, because the tags you used do not give your question the necessary visibility.

Comment: OpenGL can't draw multi-threaded.  Your draw calls will eventually be serialised down so the driver can execute them one by one. So at some point you're going to come up against a critical section eventually.  Threaded submission of draw calls is not the same as threaded execution.  At least this is my understanding :-).  There's a fascinating seminar on multi-threaded rendering for Civ V somewhere on the Intel website.  I advice you to hunt it down because it's got lots of top tips in it.  Sorry I can't find it right now.

Comment: But adding semaphores to the sections with OpenGL would solve this right?

Comment: @Kaj Toet: I'm not sure you really need semaphores, since the drawing is serialized anyway. What Robinson is saying is that you have implicit critical sections because of the way openGL works that don't allow your program to scale.

Comment: Yes, OpenGL is statebased (I think that was the correct term) and thus I used semaphores on the (implicit) critical sections to make sure it stays serialized. However a lot of my heavier code does not directly involve OpenGL calls, and thus should be able to be multithreaded.

Comment: you should check how much time is spent in the opengl parts, and how much time is spent in the non opengl parts.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I should do that, am going to right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the semaphores you added create a critical section that is either too long or too contended (or both), you will have scalability problems, because not all threads are allowed to execute the code at the same time and waiting on a semaphore triggers a context-switch, which adds further overheads.

In general, your parallel application containing a serial portion cannot scale more than the parallel portion divided by the number of cores, as per [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Without any concrete code, I cannot think of any other advice to give you.

Comment: The critical section is only based on the OpenGL output. All calculations are outside these sections, thus it should make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Kaj Toet: Any other synchronization inside those functions you are calling in the `run` method? Are you doing a lot of memory operations?

Comment: No, not a lot memory operations. But I am calling the same object with each thread, so I'm wondering if that could be it? (Not writing to it though, ofcourse)

Comment: It could be possible that you are saturating the memory bandwidth. How frequent are the reads?

Comment: There is no way to check that is there? Through profiling ie? Anyway, I do about 30 (FPS) * 64^2 * 4 * 128bit of memory reads, maybe a small multitude of that, so I should be fine.

Comment: Yes profiling should be able to tell if there is a memory bandwidth issue. In fact it's probably the best way to detect it.

Comment: I tried getting information about memory bandwidth before, and came to the conclusion that it can barely be done. In either case, I can not find the feature in valgrind.